# Get an activerecord relation from a model that is lazy loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I know ActiveRecord has lazy loaded queries where you can add filters to the already existing query and the query is called at the end.

Example: Model.where(filter1: true).where.not(filter2: true).....

In my code, I have a conditional that adds a slice filter to the query if it should be sliced and uses another model if it is not sliced. The code is as follows:

```
def base_query
  @base_query ||= slice? ? slice_class.where(slice_value: @slice.value, slice_type: @slice.type) : hour_class
end
```

The problem is that this creates inconsistent return types. An ActiveRecord relation if the thing is sliced otherwise it returns an ActiveRecord model.

If I add `.all` at the end of `hour_class` it will become consistent, but it will hit the DB at this point. How do I make this consistent without losing the lazy loading?

I am on Rails 5.0.3 and ActiveRecord 5.0.6

Comment: what about `hour_class.all`? It should not hit the database as long as you don't access the relation that it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `hour_class.default_scoped`. If you want to ignore any default scope you can use `hour_class.unscoped`.